# Push Object to Array UseState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning ReactJs, and building a sample project. I am facing a problem while pushing the items to the array. My application has a list(10 items) and I am trying to push props to an array; But I am facing the below issues:

1. On click of "Choose" button, first time item does not push into the array, but it pushes on the second click.
2. When I click on the other **li** item the first item pushed to the array is deleted and the second item pushes to it.

I am trying to solve this for the last few hours, I tried other solutions on this platform but nothing works. What I am doing wrong.

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';
    const MItem = (props)=>{
    
        const [nameList, setName] = useState([]);
       
        const NameHandler = ()=>{
              setName(nameList => [...nameList, props]);
        }
      return (
   <div>
        <div>
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>    
        <img src={props.pic} />
        <p>{props.year}</p>
        </div>
          <div>
           <button onClick={NameHandler}> Choose </button>
         </div>
        </div>
        
     )
    }
    export default MItem;
```

Comment: please share more of your code - how is `MItem` being rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume, you sent `test` using the attribute `value` as below

```
<MItem value="test">
```

Now you should use `props.value` not `props`

```
setName(nameList => [...nameList, props.value]);
```

Here is your example:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
const MItem = (props)=>{

    const [nameList, setName] = useState([]);
   
    const NameHandler = ()=>{
          setName(nameList => [...nameList, props.value]);
    }
  return (
    <button onClick={NameHandler}> Choose </button>
 )
}
export default MItem;
```

[More detail](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: The props is an array of Object, so basically I want to push object to array, when someone clicks on the button

Comment: Do I have to create an object first them push it to the array?

Comment: Please check my answer carefully. you cannot use `props` only must use `props.someproperty` and `someproperty` should be mentioned in your parent component. Now what you pass from your parent component? array or object? if `object` then my example is ok but if `array` then you need to use spread operator `...props.value` like `setName(nameList => [...nameList, ...props.value]);`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to pass a function to setName you can just do.
Based on your comments

```
const NameHandler = ()=>{
      const item = {title: props.title, pic: props.pic}

      setName([...nameList, item]);
}
```